# Word count for sections displayed (using the :target selector)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this:

```js
var editor = document.getElementById('editor');
var words = document.querySelector('.words');

function wordsCount() {
  var arr = editor.innerText.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' ');
  words.textContent = !arr[0] ? 0 : arr.length;
}
wordsCount();
```

```css
section {
  display: none;
}

:target {
  display: block;
}

.words:before {
  content: "words: "
}

.words {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#1">Show 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">Show 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">Show 3</a></li>
  </ol>
</aside>

<div id="editor">
  <section id="1">Section 1 text</section>
  <section id="2">Section 2 text</section>
  <section id="3">Section 3 text</section>
</div>

<div class="words"></div>
```

**Note:** Right now, for the word count to work I need to delete:

```
section {
  display: none;
}
```

---

**My question is:** How do I make the word count script target (count) only sections that are displayed, and only those. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach `click` event to `a` element, pass `this.hash` from index `1` to `wordsCount()`, use `RegExp` `/[^\s]+/g` and `String.prototype.match()`

```js
var editor = document.getElementById('editor');
var words = document.querySelector('.words');

function wordsCount(el) {
  var arr = el.textContent.trim().match(/[^\s]+/g);
  words.textContent = !arr[0] ? 0 : arr.length;
}
document.querySelectorAll("a")
.forEach(function(el) {
  el.onclick = function() {
    wordsCount(document.getElementById(this.hash.slice(1)))
  }
})
```

```css
section {
  display: none;
}

:target {
  display: block;
}

.words:before {
  content: "words: "
}

.words {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#1">Show 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">Show 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">Show 3</a></li>
  </ol>
</aside>

<div id="editor">
  <section id="1">Section 1 text a</section>
  <section id="2">Section 2 text b c</section>
  <section id="3">Section 3 text d e f</section>
</div>

<div class="words"></div>
```

Comment: I am about to vote your answer as the correct one because I found it simpler. Now, I have a bug with this code. If I write` index.html#1` directly in the URL, it doesn't work (I think because no click have been recorded) any idea to do this.

Comment: @Lucas You can use `load` event of `window`, check if `location.hash` is not an empty string, is not an empty string substitute `location.hash` for `this.hash` at `document.getElementById(this.hash.slice(1))`

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the length of words on click event of the anchor tag.

***Stack Snippet***

```js
var words = document.querySelector('.words');
var anchor = document.querySelectorAll("a");
var section = document.querySelectorAll("section");

for (let i = 0; i < anchor.length; i++) {
  anchor[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var arr = document.getElementById(i + 1).innerText.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' ');
    words.textContent = !arr[0] ? 0 : arr.length;
  })
}
```

```css
section {
  display: none;
}

:target {
  display: block;
}

.words:before {
  content: "words: "
}

.words {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#1">Show 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">Show 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">Show 3</a></li>
  </ol>
</aside>

<div id="editor">
  <section id="1">Section 1 text 2</section>
  <section id="2">Section 2 text</section>
  <section id="3">Section 3 text 3 4</section>
</div>

<div class="words"></div>
```